# Why am I not getting the size of the images

Tags: python, list, numpy, opencv

I have `374` `32x32` images that I read and stored in a list as follows:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(image_directory):
    for i in range(number_of_images):
        img = cv2.imread(root + '/' + str(i) + '.jpg')
        real_images.append(img)
```

when I wanted to return the shape of `real_images` by doing: `numpy.array(real_images).shape`, I got `(374,)`.

Why didn't I get `(374, 32, 32, 3)`? That is, the number of images along with their dimensions?

Thanks.

Comment: `z = [cv2.imread('5by10.bmp') for _ in range(10)]; np.array(z).shape --> (10, 10, 5, 3)` ... works for me.

Comment: Maybe there is an image with different shape?

Comment: What does this say? `set(x.shape for x in real_images)`

Comment: Please show how you initialize the array you are appending to. If I had to guess, it has dtype= np.object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @HaBom said in the comment might be the case. I tried the following and got a similar result as yours.

```
import numpy as np

a = []
for i in range(10):
    a.append(np.arange(10))
print(np.array(a).shape)
a.append(np.array([1]))
print(np.array(a).shape)

Output:
(10,10)
(11,)
```

Try checking the shapes of individual `np` array if you can. Maybe it will tell you what is happening. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Yes, I noticed that an image with the name "0.jpg" didn't exist, and that caused the issue, provided that it had the shape "( )" since it didn't exist.

Comment: Glad I could be of help :-)